# How to create a screen on socket exception in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, exception, socketexception

In my flutter project I need to show some illustration images when socket exception occurs when API was called. How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help on socket exception and format exception.

Create model class for httpresponse

```
class HTTPResponse<T> {
  bool isSuccessful;
  T data;
  String message;
  int responseCode;
  HTTPResponse(this.isSuccessful, this.data, {this.message, this.responseCode});
}
```

Then use this model in api response like this

```
Future<HTTPResponse<List<Post>>> getPosts(
      {int limit = 20, int page = 1}) async {
    String url =
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=$limit&_page=$page';
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

    try {
      var response = await http.get(uri);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var body = json.decode(response.body);
        List<Post> postsList = [];
        body.forEach((e) {
          Post post = Post.fromJson(e);
          postsList.add(post);
        });
        return HTTPResponse(
          true,
          postsList,
          responseCode: response.statusCode,
        );
      } else {
        return HTTPResponse(false, null,
            message: 'Invalid response from server',
            responseCode: response.statusCode);
      }
    } on SocketException {
      return HTTPResponse(false, [], message: 'Unable to reach the internet');
    } on FormatException {
      return HTTPResponse(false, [], message: 'Invalid response from server');
    } catch (e) {
      return HTTPResponse(false, [],
          message: "Something went wrong please try in a minute or two");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you want to show it in the widget tree. One simple example would be to push a new screen on to the navigation stack. You will need the BuildContext in your function where the exception might occur.

```
void someMethod(BuildContext context) {
    try {
      //some code that might throw an exception
    } on Exception catch (_) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, "Your illustration view");
    }
  }
```

Another example would be to add it to your widget tree depending on a bool. You set that bool to true when an exception is thrown.

```
void someOtherMethod() {
    try {
      //some code that might throw an exception
    } on Exception catch (_) {
      setState(() {
      hasThrownError = true; 
      });
    }
  }
```

Use it in your widget tree like so:

```
bool hasThrownError = false;

  Widget buildWidgetTree() {
    return hasThrownError
        ? Text("This is where you can show your error illustration")
        : Text("This is wher you can show your regular view");
  }
```